# Print Syntax Incorrect

Tags: python

What is wrong with the syntax here?

```
print '#' * 25, 'IMPLEMENTATION FOR %s', '#' * 25 % initialize.ntw_device[index].hostname
```

Here is part of the output:

```
######################### IMPLEMENTATION FOR %s
 line 11, in shift_off_confirm
        print '#' * 25, 'IMPLEMENTATION FOR %s', '#' * 25 % initialize.ntw_device[index].hostname
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: As a simpler example, consider why `print("A", "%s", "C" % "B")` would give the same error.

Comment: `%` is a string operator, applied here to `####################...`. It's not part of the `print` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is in second part of print statement. Because when you write

```
'IMPLEMENTATION FOR %s', '#' * 25 % "test"
```

%s needs to be replaced but you don't. So it should be like this.

```
print '#' * 25, 'IMPLEMENTATION FOR %s %s'  % ('#' * 25, initialize.ntw_device[index].hostname)
```

And also maybe you should consider using `format` function instead of `%`s.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator is string operator, more akin to C's `sprintf` than `printf`. It's not part of the `print` statement. What you've written is akin to

```
print '#' * 25,
print 'IMPLEMENTATION FOR %s',
print '#' * 25 % initialize.ntw_device[index].hostname
```

There is no format specifier in `'#' # 25` for the hostname to fill, resulting in the error. You can write either

```
print '#' * 25, \
      'IMPLEMENTATION FOR %s' % (initialize.ntw_device[index].hostname,) \
      '#' * 25
```

or

```
print ('#' * 25 + 'IMPLEMENTATION FOR %s' + '#' * 25) % (initialize.ntw_device[index].hostname,)
```

It's considered good practice to always an explicit tuple instead of a single value as the right-hand argument, to guard against the possibility that the RHA evaluates to a tuple itself.